# Почему основной код на с++ обязательно должен лежать в функции main()?

Tags: c++, стандарт

Почему основной код на с++ обязательно должен лежать в функции main() и в принципе какой либо `statement` без функции работать не будет? Я понимаю, то что это требования стандарта, но почему бы нельзя было сделать так, чтобы это работало без функции?

Comment: Экономят бумагу. Текущий стандарт языка и так занимает 1800 страниц не особо крупным шрифтом, а если позволить всяким `statement` выполняться вне функций, стандарт увеличится в объёме процентов на 30 :D

Comment: а если будет несколько cpp файлов, то как определить, какой и в каком порядке нужно вначале выполнять?

Comment: @KoVadim, вы только что подали ТС идею для очередного вопроса :D

Comment: так это известная проблема - static fiasco!

Comment: @KoVadim, так и я о чём. Тут уже скоро будет 50 лет как не могут решить проблему порядка инициализации глобальных переменных, а ТС хочет ещё и всякие стейтменты наружу вынести.

Comment: А  смысл? Ведь если сделать так, например, как в Паскале - вы же спросите, а почему не сделать основной код в функции `main`? Так какая разница?... Да, кстати, а вас не интересует, почему в C++ нет вложенных функций?

Comment: как это нет? есть конечно. и их целый вагон.

Comment: @Harry, интересует, но вроде бы они есть. Я извиниюсь, т. к. я новичок в этом деле и могу говорить не совсем верные вещи. Вроде как это lambda-функции, но они идут в доп. библиотеке.

Comment: лямбды уже почти 10 лет часть языка.

Comment: Лямбды не есть чистые функции, как в Паскале...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо понял, но можете пожалуйста назвать причину по которой нет "чистых" вложенных функций.

Comment: Это - к Кернигану и Ричи, увы, уже только через медиумов... Вы во всем хотите найти какую-то причину, а ее может как таковой просто не быть. Например, почему Паскаль нечувствителен к регистру, а С/С++ - наоборот? Думаете, есть хоть какая-то конкретная причина? Да как в [этой байке](https://habr.com/ru/post/73188/)... Вот такой язык решили сделать. Все можно - что не запрещено законами природы. Можно в С добавить вложенные функции, можно - многопроходность, можно на борту самолета сделать бассейн... Но вот так вот решили создатели - давайте на чем-то остановимся, нет?

Comment: @Harry, да понял, извините.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насчет того, что основной код должен лежать в main вот пример, когда это не так

```cpp
struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    }
};

A a;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Насчет `statement`, зачем это делать, когда можно занести код в функцию. Так
и более читабельный код будет.

Comment: А вы попробуйте без `main` совсем обойтись :)

Comment: если нужно, то можно. Можно другую функцию использовать как entry point, А можно вообще бинарный код в char* переменную поместить.

Comment: да запросто есть же WinMain.

Comment: главное знать, как именно работает winmain